# Is there a way to find required fields on an objects?

Tags: page-layout, fields

Is there an easy way to find the required fields for an objects? Is page layout the only way to see visually what fields are required for an object?

**I am looking for a GUI tool not code.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have a way to see both fields required by page layout AND field level. It's an important difference - field level required or page layout required...

In standard salesforce, I don't think there's an easy way to quickly list required fields.

On the appexchange there are some apps available but I think they will only look at the field details and not take into account when fields are made required on the page layout.

The apps that I looked at before:
"Object Metadata Snapshot Tool" (mind the reviews and comments on failing tests)

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Ih3aEAC

Etherios Easydescribe:
(still had this link somewhere in my mails but the app doesn't seem visible anymore on the appexchange)

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ

Answer (score 8):

I think you can infer it, if a field *is* `Createable` and *not* `Nillable` and *not* `DefaultedOnCreate`.

```
SObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Createable &&
!SObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Nillable &&
!SObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.DefaultedOnCreate
```

The DescribeFieldResult does not surface this directly (thanks [Farid Kognoz](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008mLKIAY))

If you don't mind to use the SOAP API, you could also noodle at [DescribeLayoutResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describelayout_describelayoutresult.htm) `required` attributes, though it's trickier and not all of an object's fields may be on the page layout.

Comment: I am looking for a GUI tool not code

Comment: Nice solution @bigassforce
I tried it with Contact object as i know LastName is mandatory in Contact.
`Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();`


`Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> M = r.fields.getMap();
for(String fieldName : M.keySet()) { 
    Schema.SObjectField field = M.get(fieldName);
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = field.getDescribe();
    if(F.isCreateable() && !F.isNillable() && !F.isDefaultedOnCreate())
     System.debug ('F = ' + fieldName);
}`